# Cyclic label update in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to get dynamic cyclic (every half a second) label updates from a Webservice in Python where I parse a JSON string and return its contents to the GUI (made with Glade 3.8.1).

I have started from a basic example and the code I've written so far looks like this:

```
import sys
import json
import urllib2
import time

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk.glade
    import gtk
except:
    sys.exit(1)

class cRioHMI():

    def on_MainWindow_destroy(self, data = None):
        print "quit with cancel"
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, data = None):
        print "quit from menu"
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_btnTest_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Button Pressed"

    def on_gtk_about_activate(self, data = None):
        print "About Page Accessed"
        self.response = self.about.run()
        self.about.hide()

    def __init__(self):

        self.gladefile = "Assets/HMI.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("MainWindow")
        self.about = self.builder.get_object("AboutDialogue")
        self.templable = self.builder.get_object("lbl_Temperature")
        self.window.show()

    def update_Values(self, data = None):
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://10.10.10.11:8001/WebUI/Temperatures/GetTemperatures')
        data = json.load(response)
        temperature = data['Temperature2'][1]
        self.templable.set_text(str(temperature))
        time.sleep(.5)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    HMI = cRioHMI()
    gtk.main()
```

When I use the code from the update_Values method on a click event, the code performs as expected

```
    def on_btnTest_clicked(self, widget):
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://10.10.10.11:8001/WebUI/Temperatures/GetTemperatures')
    data = json.load(response)
    temperature = data['Temperature2'][1]
    self.templable.set_text(str(temperature))
    time.sleep(.5)
    print "Button Pressed"
```

- but I would like to update multiple labels in a cyclic manner and still have event driven actions.

What is the best way to do that? Please note, that I'm new to python.

Comment: You should never, ever `sleep` (or do _anything_ that could block for a long time, but `sleep` is especially bad because it's guaranteed to block, and does nothing else) in a GUI event handler. You either need to move the work that requires sleeping to a background thread, or use the event loop itself by setting a timer. For the second one, see [Timeouts, IO, and Idle Functions](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html) in the PyGtk2 tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gobject.timeout_add` (see the documentation [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add)).

So in your `__init__` you would have something like `gobject.timeout_add(1000, self.updateValues)`. If you return False the timeout will not be called again.

You should also not use `time.sleep`. This is a blocking call. That means your GUI will freeze as it cannot handle incoming events. The same thing will happen with the `urllib2.urlopen` call, if it takes too much time. To prevent this you can run updateValues in a separate Thread. Then you would have to use `gobject.idle_add` to set the text of the label (see [documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add)).

Here is a small example. It is just a counter (and would not need threading) but I marked the place where your urllib2.urlopen would go with a comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from threading import Thread
from pygtk import gtk, gobject

class Window(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
        self.label = gtk.Label('1')
        self.add(self.label)
        gobject.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.threaded)

    def threaded(self):
        thread = Thread(target=self.updateValues)
        thread.start()
        return True

    def updateValues(self):
        # urllib.urlopen calls
        n = int(self.label.get_text())
        gobject.idle_add(self.label.set_text, str(n + 1))

win = Window()
win.show_all()
gobject.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```